# On click event for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

First of all, I know this has been answered a lot of times, but all the things I try to do, they're not working. So here's my problem:

I have  a non-displayed div that I want to show when the users clicks a div, so I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hamburger-menu").on("click", function(){
        var display = $(".menu-mobile").css("display");
        if (display == "none") {
            $(".menu-mobile").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(".menu-mobile").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

This works perfectly on my desktop but doesn't work in my mobile.
What I found in the other answers was to change the **.on("click")** value to **.on("click touchstart")** or **.on("tap")**, but they both don't work.

So what's the problem? I have another animation that doesn't require any click event and it works perfectly and smoothly on my mobile. Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: One suggestion, instead of `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hamburger-menu").on("click", function(){
        var display = $(".menu-mobile").css("display");
        if (display == "none") {
            $(".menu-mobile").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(".menu-mobile").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}); `  could you not do   `$(".hamburger-menu").on("click", function(){ $(".menu-mobile").toggle();`

Comment: @Billy Oh, yes! Sorry, I'm not really into javascript so I didn't really know this function existed.... Hahahahaha thanks! ;)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help with the actual problem, Don't know too much about web designing for mobile, Good luck though..

Comment: @Billy Don't worry! Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are some issues with jquery and detecting touches. i find it best to set event listeners with javascript for this sort of thing. I've had luck with something like this:

```
this.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){happens(e)}, false);
```

`touchend` is a good `mouseup` equivalent for mobile. `touchstart` should work for `mousedown` like you were trying.