# Making a mobile navigation appear on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a mobile menu appear when the burger icon is clicked using javascript but can't seem to make it work. Can someone help? I have attached the code below, at the moment the menu is hidden to the right of the screen due to the transform property but when I click the burger Icon I would like to reveal this. Does the problem lie in calling a css property that is attached to a parent element?

***HTML***

```
<header>
    <a href="/stjohnschurch" class="nav-brand">
        <img src="http://dev.righthookstudio.co.uk/stjohnschurch/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/St-Johns-Church.png" alt="st johns logo">
    </a>
    <nav>

    <?php wp_nav_menu(
         array (
            'theme_location' => 'primary-navigation',
            'menu_class' => 'primary-navigation'
        )
    );?>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
header .primary-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 8vh;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5 ease-in;
}
header .primary-navigation li {
    opacity: 0;
}
.burger {
    display: block;
}
.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}}
```

***Javascript***

```
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('header > .primary-navigation');

burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
}); } navSlide()
```

Comment: What do you even mean by _“calling a css property that is attached to a parent element”_? What have you done to try and _debug_ this so far? Have you verified that the JavaScript runs, and that it correctly selected the elements you expected it to …?

Comment: Lol sorry, `const nav` is selecting the css property `header .primary-navigation` but I'm unsure how to call this in javascript. I used VSCode debugger but pretty new at all this

Comment: So, managed to get this working by removing the header parent class from my CSS and Javascript - now it works fine. However, I would like to know in the future how you call a class in javascript which is attached to a parent. So, in this case, how do I call `header .primary-navigation` in javascript?

Comment: The actual HTML structure you have probably doesn’t match the selector `header > .primary-navigation`. Is `http://dev.righthookstudio.co.uk/stjohnschurch/` the page in question? There you have `header` `nav` `div` `ul` nested into each other, and the `ul` is the element with the class `primary-navigation`. So `header > .primary-navigation` can’t find anything, because the element with that class is not a child of `header`, it is only a descendant further down.

Comment: Maybe this will help.
Use eventListener touch for mobile.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961140/on-click-event-for-mobile#answer-26961247