# dark background-color when pressing button

Tags: html, css, carousel

I try to implement a carousel with buttons to go back and forth. When I press the buttons on my pc there is no problem but once I press them on my phone the background-color turns gray.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyxqi.png)

Neither in my CSS nor in my HTML is a background-color which could interfere…

```
.prev-screen,
  .next-screen {
    align-self: stretch;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgba(#000, 0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 1;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1000;

    &:hover,
    &:active {
      color: #000;
      transform-origin: center;
      transform: scale(1.25);
    }

    &:disabled {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

What could lead to that black background?

Comment: This is just black with opacity 0.25

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you provided doesn't describe exactly what you have written to change the background color. What code have you wrote to add the active class to the background? Either way, it might be because of the event listener you have set up to alter css properties... if it works on pc and not on mobile... this might help you out?, or at least guide you on your way... [On click event for mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961140/on-click-event-for-mobile).

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless I found another solution! All I had to use was `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`